# Teradata jdbc executeBatch throws a weird error?

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

I use `jdbc` to load raw data sets to Teradata. I has been working **PERFECT** until recently.

Here is the code

```
    try { 
        prst.executeBatch(); 
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) {  
            System.out.println("Batch outside the loop error: ");
             while (ex != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(" Error code: " + ex.getErrorCode());
                    System.out.println(" SQL State: " + ex.getSQLState());
                    System.out.println(" Message: " + ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println();
                    ex = ex.getNextException();
                }

        }
```

But yesterday the same code statred throwing an error. Here is the error

```
    [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 13.00.00.16] [Error 1339] [SQLState HY000] 
A failure occurred while executing a PreparedStatement batch request. 
The parameter set was not executed and should be resubmitted
 individually using the PreparedStatement executeUpdate method
```

I checked using `getNextException()` but all I get is the same message

```
A failure occurred while executing a PreparedStatement batch request. 
    The parameter set was not executed and should be resubmitted
     individually using the PreparedStatement executeUpdate method
```

It's repeating the same stuff all over again without any further details. I tried to decrease the batch size to a minimum as recomended [here](https://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/errors-teradata-jdbc-driver-terajdbc-13-00-00-16-error-1339-sqlstate-hy000)  but still no result.

What could possible cause this error  ?  How to overcome it ?

Comment: You'll need to add your code above the try/catch. whats going on before the execute batch. Also what might have changed recently to cause a consistent failure?

Comment: Nothing changed recently. Not a thing. A prepared statement `prst.executeBatch();` throws an error. Usually this error happens because of the large batch size. But i reduced it to a minimum

Comment: Error 1339 is a very generic error. Somewhere in your stack trace you should hopefully have a SQLException.  You may not be able to get to it with that old of a driver though, based on this [documentation](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#CCHJHFDI).

Comment: How do you prepare? Could you paste the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue recently:

1. if you can,  identify the smallest subset of data that gives you the error
2. modify the code to be optionally launched without batching (not for production use)

In my case it was a single numeric value whose precision was more than the column it was inserted in,  but generally that error message is hiding whatever issue you're encountering (a field too large?  No more disk space?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the Teradata JDBC Driver documentation for the BatchUpdateException: https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#CCHJHFDI

As the documentation says, Error 1339 means that you are getting the old batch error behavior. One or more of the rows in your batch have problems, but the JDBC Driver is unable to identify which rows have a problem.

If you switch to a newer version of the JDBC Driver (and you may need a newer version of the database also) then a new feature "Statement Independence" is available that identifies which rows have a problem, and what the problem is for each row.

You can download the Teradata JDBC Driver from Maven Central or from the Teradata download site: https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver