# How to store long values in a table using PreparedStatement in JDBC?

Tags: java, prepared-statement, teradata, batch-processing, bulkinsert

I have a teradata table :

```
 CREATE SET TABLE P_D.SAMPLE
 (
  ID DECIMAL(18,0),
  ISBN DECIMAL(18,0),
  TITLE varchar(100) null,
  POSITION INT
)
```

I would like to batch insert from java:

```
 private static final String INSERT = "INSERT INTO P_D.SAMPLE (ID,ISBN,TITLE,POSITION) "
        + "VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

 public void insert(List<Book> books) {
  int booksCount = 0;
  int batch_size = 15000;

  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT);
            for (Book book : books) {
                preparedStatement.setLong(1, book.geId());
                preparedStatement.setLong(2,book.getIsbn());
                preparedStatement.setString(3, book.getTitle());
                preparedStatement.setInt(4, book.getPosition());
                preparedStatement.addBatch();

                if (++booksCount % batch_size == 0) {
                    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
                }
            }
            preparedStatement.executeBatch(); //inserting the remaining books
            preparedStatement.close();
 }
```

I am getting the following error:

[Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.10.00.03] [Error 1339] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while executing a PreparedStatement batch request. The parameter set was not executed and should be resubmitted individually using the PreparedStatement executeUpdate method.

Any thoughts?

I tried to run each statement individually as you suggested below and I got an error :
 [Error 2644] [SQLState HY000] No more room in database

Comment: DECIMAL(0,18) is this correct? Shouldn't it be DECIMAL(18,0)?

Comment: Execute a single executeUpdate and see if that runs properly or throws some light to what is wrong here. REFER: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731117/teradata-jdbc-executebatch-throws-a-weird-error

Comment: 1339 is a very generic error.  I **think** it's basically telling you that there are errors with the individual rows within the batch. Been a while, but I think you can get individual exceptions from your exception object -  e.getNextException() maybe?

Comment: Where is the exception happening? Is it in the executeBatch inside the loop or outside? Where is the transaction committed?

Comment: I run your suggestions and I got an error : No more room in database

Comment: This may help. http://www.nazmulhuda.info/failure-2644-no-more-room-in-database-dataasename-while-there-is-space-available

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions in the P_D database?

Answer (score 0):

Teradata Database Error 2644 "No more room in database" literally means that there is no more room in the database. There is no more permanent space available in the database.

To get past this error, you can either increase the perm space of the database, or you can drop some existing objects (such as tables) from the database.